ggplot2 change graph attributes like certain linewidth or graph size?
A function from an R package returns a ggplot2 plot object. How do I change the attributes in it, like in Python matplotlib, I can access the fig.axes[0].set_... functions?
There are a lot of tutorials telling me how to correctly set the figure params while plotting, but none tells me how to change them once the plot is already done and I cannot access the code that acctually made the plot.
I am using ipynb. It is a directed graph plot with many points and arrowed edges. I want to change the width of the edges.
I tried plot$layers[[0]]$... but I did not find a function that changes the line width of a certain line. (It is a directed graph plot with many points and arrowed edges. I want to change the width of the edges.)

I've used
p[["layers"]][[1]][["aes_params"]][["linewidth"]] <- .5
to change the linewidth

Can you let us know which package it is you need help with, since the possibility to edit differs per package? Plus, what would you like to change? Is there a reproducible example that you can provide? Perhaps a test/example object from the package itself?
Additionally, packages often have a Github (or comparable) repo that stores a.o. its functions. If nothing else works - unlikely - you can often copy the original function and adjust it to your needs.

@MichielDuvekot This worked! Thanks so much

In my experience it varies from package to package. In some cases you can add layers in other cases you have to pass arguments to the function that produced the plot. Take the interflex example
library(interflex)
#> ## Syntax has changed since v.1.2.1.
#> ## Comments and suggestions -> zyliu2020@uchicago.edu.
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(modelsummary)
library(ggplot2)

penguins = palmerpenguins::penguins |>
  drop_na() |> 
  mutate(species = as_factor(species),
         species = fct_relevel(species, 'Adelie', after = 1)) |>
  as.data.frame()


est = interflex(estimator = 'kernel', data = penguins, 
                Y = 'body_mass_g', D = 'bill_depth_mm',
                X = 'bill_length_mm', Z = c('species', 'flipper_length_mm'))
#> Cross-validating bandwidth ... 
#> Parallel computing with 4 cores...
#> Optimal bw=3.6354.
#> Number of evaluation points:50
#> Parallel computing with 4 cores...
#> 

##
underlying_figure = est$figure

underlying_figure + labs(x = 'this is not going to work')


  
est = interflex(estimator = 'kernel', data = penguins, 
                Y = 'body_mass_g', D = 'bill_depth_mm',
                X = 'bill_length_mm', Z = c('species', 'flipper_length_mm'),
               ylab = 'This Will Work')
#> Cross-validating bandwidth ... 
#> Parallel computing with 4 cores...
#> Optimal bw=4.1604.
#> Number of evaluation points:50
#> Parallel computing with 4 cores...
#> 
  
est$figure


For modelsummary you can pass off arguments directly to modelplot which will pass them off to the underlying geom. You can also bypass that which takes a bit more work. In some cases you can get the underlying that was used to draw the plot via ggplot_build
  

examp_mod = lm(body_mass_g ~ species*flipper_length_mm , data = penguins)

base_plot  =  modelplot(examp_mod) 

## in this example I had to find how the geom was plotted
with_differences = base_plot +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x = estimate, y = term ,xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high), linewidth = 20)


  with_differences / base_plot 


## sometimes you can get the underlying data 
  
base_data = ggplot_build(base_plot) |>
  pluck('plot', 'data')
  
  ggplot(base_data, aes(x = term, y = estimate)) +
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymax = conf.high, ymin = conf.low)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0)


Created on 2024-07-16 with reprex v2.1.1
